# Download page from SharePoint Online using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

How can I download the contents of a page on my SharePoint Online (Office 365) environment using PowerShell? This is an `.aspx` page - I am looking for the rendered/html version, same as if I went there on my browser, not looking for the source code.

I would prefer a simple `WebRequest` call, but haven't been able to get the credentialing to work. I have tried many variations of the following, all of which return a 403:

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$webclient.AuthenticationMode = "FormsAuthentication"
$webclient.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo($username, $password)
```

I have also tried the SharePoint Online client libraries. I can successfully connect to my environment using the code below, but don't know how to request a particular page from there:

```
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$userName = "UserName"
$password = "Password"
$pageUrl = "PageUrl"
$localPath = "C:\Path\FileName.aspx"

#create secure password
$sPassword = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webClient.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $sPassword)
$webClient.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
$webClient.DownloadFile($pageUrl, $localPath)
$webClient.Dispose()
```

Comment: Here's a follow-up question: Is there a way to parse the DOM of this page without saving it to disk?